# How to debug Cron Jobs on Google App Engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-platform

## Situation

Cron is (alongside the Rails app), deployed to GCP with `cron.yaml`:

```
cron:
- description: count things regularly
  url: /api/v1/cron/rake_task
  schedule: every 30 minutes
  timezone: Europe/Berlin
```

## Problem

[image]

## Question

How to see the cron log? *View* reveals nothing at all, but clearly there has to be a sensible way to debug the failure.

On a standard environment one could go after `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/cron.log`, but here there's nothing if I log in to VM or even go after the main `gaeapp` container.

Any leads would be welcome!

Comment: start here maybe? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/writing-application-logs#viewing_logs

Comment: Also check logs for other services, including `default`, just in case the request doesn't make it to the service you're expecting it to.

Comment: Were you able to find the reason why the cron jobs failed?

Comment: There was a business logic error in the application itself. Nothing wrong with the GAE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cron log gets populated into the log of default service.

Instead of *View* link log of default service should be filtered for the Rake task route that the cron is calling.

Answer (score -1):

I have a base http request handler that all the other request handlers inherit. I wrapped it up in a try-catch so that I can email myself the stack trace every time an exception occurs.

Here is how I did it in python/webapp2, I'm sure you could setup something similar in ruby. (alternatively you could use a product like https://rollbar.com/)

```
from google.appengine.api import mail, app_identity

def email_dev(subject, body):
    try:
        app_id = app_identity.get_application_id()
        mail.AdminEmailMessage(
            sender="%s <no-reply@%s.appspotmail.com>" % (app_id, app_id),
            subject=subject,
            body=body,
        ).send()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error sending email: "+str(e))


class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super(BaseHandler, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception:
            email_dev(
                "Handler: "+self.__class__.__name__+" failed",
                traceback.format_exc())
            raise
```

Comment: Sorry, but the question was about cron logs in order to identify failure. If cron fails and GCP GUI displays failure, the knowledge exists, it should produce a corresponding failure entry somewhere, but it's not in the logs.