# Rails Cron on google cloud

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cron

I would like to make a simple URL request on my website through cron.

For this test, I made a route '/cron_test_method'. So when I go on the URL "https://webside.com/cron_test_method", my method is running and working !

Now, I want to do it automatically with the App Engine Cron Service (Google Cloud Platform). To do that, I have followed the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml) form Google. It looks really simple, but it is failing for me. I succeeded to push the Cron file online and run it through the Cron App Engine dashboard. But it's stated as failed.

My code :

> config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do  
  get '/cron_test_method' => 'tests#cron_method'
end
```

> app/controllers/tests_controller.rb

```
class TestsController < ApplicationController

  def cron_method
    User.first.update(cron_at: Time.now)
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

> cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: "my cron test"
  url: /cron_test_method
  schedule: every 24 hours
```

PS: I've never made a cron request in development before. I saw few techniques like with the "whenever" gem or with rake:tasks. So I'm not sure if we can do request like the one I implement it bellow. It's not really secure. So if you have better ways to achieve it, you're welcome !

Comment: By failing what do you mean?. Is there an error or the cron doesn't execute?.

Comment: yes, the cron action is not running

Comment: I usually use rake to run my cron tasks

Comment: @jacquesMesnet did you execute `gcloud app deploy cron.yaml`?

Comment: @jackesMesnet do you have many services running on your App Engine application? Did you define a firewall for the application? What error do the logs show?

Comment: Hi @sureshprasanna70, yes I did it, my cron task is present on the dashboard. But there is no logs when I run it, only the status marked as failed

Comment: If you can provide the logs of cron job or the rails app, may be we can have a shot. You can find the cron job logs by following the instruction here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48465987/how-to-debug-cron-jobs-on-google-app-engine.